# In Physx, A collision is detected in onContact() before the shape collides

Tags: physx

[image]

I'm trying the collision detection example in SampleSubmarine and I'm having a problem.

As shown in the picture, when Plane and Sphere collide, the break is made at int a = 10 of the onContact function, but the break is applied here even though there has not been a collision yet.

The size of the shape and the size of the drawn sphere are the same, but I do not know why it was before the collision.

If you don't know, I'll attach the code as well.

this is for filtershader

```
 PxFilterFlags SampleSubmarineFilterShader(
     PxFilterObjectAttributes attributes0, PxFilterData filterData0,
     PxFilterObjectAttributes attributes1, PxFilterData filterData1,
     PxPairFlags& pairFlags, const void* constantBlock, PxU32 constantBlockSize)
 {
     // let triggers through
     if (PxFilterObjectIsTrigger(attributes0) || PxFilterObjectIsTrigger(attributes1))
     {
         pairFlags = PxPairFlag::eTRIGGER_DEFAULT;
         return PxFilterFlag::eDEFAULT;
     }
     // generate contacts for all that were not filtered above
     pairFlags = PxPairFlag::eCONTACT_DEFAULT;

     // trigger the contact callback for pairs (A,B) where 
     // the filtermask of A contains the ID of B and vice versa.
     if ((filterData0.word0 & filterData1.word1) && (filterData1.word0 & filterData0.word1))
         pairFlags |= PxPairFlag::eNOTIFY_TOUCH_FOUND;

     return PxFilterFlag::eDEFAULT;
 }
```

this is for PxSimulationEventCallback

```
 class ContactCallBack : public PxSimulationEventCallback
 {
     // PxSimulationEventCallback을(를) 통해 상속됨
     virtual void onConstraintBreak(PxConstraintInfo * constraints, PxU32 count) override;
     virtual void onWake(PxActor ** actors, PxU32 count) override;
     virtual void onSleep(PxActor ** actors, PxU32 count) override;
     virtual void onContact(const PxContactPairHeader & pairHeader, const PxContactPair * pairs, PxU32 nbPairs) override;
     virtual void onTrigger(PxTriggerPair * pairs, PxU32 count) override;
     virtual void onAdvance(const PxRigidBody * const * bodyBuffer, const PxTransform * poseBuffer, const PxU32 count) override;
 };
```

this is for plane

```
 HRESULT PhysXManager::CreateSimulation()
 {
     material = physics->createMaterial(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.1f);
     auto groundPlane = PxCreatePlane(*physics, PxPlane(0, 1, 0, 1), *material);
     SetupFiltering(groundPlane, FilterGroup::eHEIGHTFIELD, FilterGroup::eSUBMARINE);
     scene->addActor(*groundPlane);


     return S_OK;
 }
```

this is for sphere

```
 HRESULT ColliderRenderer::CreateBuffer(PxGeometryType::Enum _geoType)
 {
     switch (_geoType)
     {
     case physx::PxGeometryType::eSPHERE:
         GeometricPrimitive::CreateSphere(vertices, indices, 10, 8, false); // 3rd parameter is diameter
         break;
          ....
     }
      .....
  }
```

this is for shape

```
 PxShape* Collider::AddCollider()
 {
     ColliderDesc desc;
     desc.scale = Vector3(5.f, 5.f, 5.f);
     desc.radius = 5.f;
     desc.halfHeight = 10.f;

     return PhysXManager::GetInstance()->AddCollider(geoType, desc);
 }


 PxShape* PhysXManager::AddCollider(PxGeometryType::Enum _type, ColliderDesc _desc)
 {
     PxShape* shape = nullptr;

     switch (_type)
     {
     case physx::PxGeometryType::eSPHERE:
         shape = physics->createShape(PxSphereGeometry(PxReal(_desc.radius)), *material, true);
         break;
          ...
     }
         return shape;
  }
```

Spheres and spheres, as well as collisions with spheres and planes, break before shapes collide.
Does anyone know about this?

loop code

```
while (TRUE)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    FrameTimeDefault += TimeMgr->ComputeTimer(L"Timer_Default");

    if (1.f / 60.f <= FrameTimeDefault)
    {
        physxManager->RunSimulate();

        mainApp->Update(TimeMgr->ComputeTimer(L"Timer_60"));
        mainApp->Render();


        FrameTimeDefault = 0.f;
    }
    
}
```

this is for simulation code

```
void PhysXManager::RunSimulate()
{
    scene->simulate(1.f / 60.f);
    scene->fetchResults(true);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're not drawing the frame before the collision is detected? I.e. in the game loop, you'd first do the collision detection/resolution/step, only then you would draw the result of the step.

Comment: Do you mean it is because the difference between physics simulation and drawing because of the frame? i edited my loop code

Comment: Yes, the simulation occurs before it is rendered. When you get to the first breakpoint, then add another breakpoint at `FrameTimeDefault = 0.f;`; if you're lucky, you'll see the two surfaces touch (otherwise, the ball will have bounced off of the plane already).

Comment: Mainapp->update() and mainapp->render() are executed every 60 frames, and simulation is also executed every 60 frames. Why are they different?

Comment: There was no collision in the view in the physx visual debugger.

Comment: I admit I don't know what goes on there.